# No need for initializer for optional properties inside Swift class

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, initializer

Why we don't need initializer for optional properties inside any class in `ViewController.swift` files?

```
class SpareParts {
    var wheels: Int8?
    var engine: String?
}
```

But if class's properties are non-optional we immediately need an init() method:

[image]

Comment: Optional properties default value is `nil`. Classes have default initializer. If all properties have optional values you can use default initializer.

Comment: What does default swift class initializer look like?

Comment: This is currently being discussed in the Swift forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/prepitch-optional-variables-should-require-explicit-initialization/26077.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Optional Property Types :**

If your custom type has a stored property that is logically allowed to have “no value”—perhaps because its value cannot be set during initialization, or because it is allowed to have “no value” at some later point—declare the property with an optional type. Properties of optional type are automatically initialized with a value of nil, indicating that the property is deliberately intended to have “no value yet” during initialization.

For Example :

```
class SurveyQuestion {
    var text: String?
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
    func ask() {
        print(text)
    }
}

let cheeseQuestion = SurveyQuestion(text: "Do you like cheese?")
cheeseQuestion.ask()
// Prints "Do you like cheese?"
 let cheeseQuestion1 = SurveyQuestion()
cheeseQuestion.ask() 
// Prints nil
```

Answer (score 1):

> We don't need initializer for optional properties

Because it's default is `nil` , regrading the non-optional it can't be so you have to assign a value with `init` or get a compile-time error like what you currently have

Comment: So, there's no so called `default class initializer` as @EmreCiftci says, right?

Comment: optional default value is `nil` so it will compile and when you access it will print nil unlike non-optional that should know from where to get it's value when a class instance is created